# data set " SAT12" not found

Tags: r

I'm a beginer in R , and trying to the below code. 
But, "data set " SAT12" not found" appears 
Thank you for your response in advance

```
data("SAT12")
data <- key2binary(SAT12, key = c(1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 
                                  1, 5, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 
                                  1, 3, 1, 5, 4, 5))
specific <- c(2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3,
              3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2)
guess <- rep(0.1, 32)
b_mod1 <- bfactor(data, specific, guess)
coef(b_mod1)
```

Comment: `install.packages("sos"); library(sos); findFn("SAT12")`

Comment: In other words, have you installed the appropriate package that holds this dataset? If yes, have you called it in your active R session via `library()` or `require()`?